# I have create my first project using JavaScript, It's a Pomodoro Clock, I am learning JavaScript, is it a good code or not

Tags: javascript

**Description:**
I recently completed my first JavaScript project, a Pomodoro clock, without relying on tutorials. I'd like feedback on my code to improve my skills further. Here's a detailed overview of how I implemented it:

```js
console.log("Happy Coding, with Pomodoro Timer!");

const break_time_adjustments = () => {
  // Getting all elements to set the length of Break
  const increase_break_time_button = document.querySelector(
      ".break-length-div .value-adjustment .plus"
    ),
    decrease_break_time_button = document.querySelector(
      ".break-length-div .value-adjustment .minus"
    ),
    break_time_value = document.querySelector(
      ".break-length-div .value-adjustment .minutes"
    );

  // Performing Operations on the elements
  let break_time = 5;
  break_time_value.innerHTML = break_time;

  // Getter function to retrieve the current brake time
  const get_break_time = () => break_time;

  // Setter funtion to set the update the break time and display it
  const set_break_time = (new_time) => {
    break_time = new_time;
    break_time_value.innerHTML = break_time;
  };

  // Increasing the length of Break
  function increase_break_time() {
    set_break_time(break_time + 5); // Increasing the break time by 5
  }

  increase_break_time_button.addEventListener("click", increase_break_time);

  // Decreasing the length of Break
  function decrease_break_time() {
    if (break_time <= 0) {
      break_time = 0;
    } else {
      set_break_time(break_time - 5); // Decreasing the break time by 5
    }
  }

  decrease_break_time_button.addEventListener("click", decrease_break_time);

  return {
    get_break_time,
    set_break_time
  };
};

const {
  get_break_time,
  set_break_time
} = break_time_adjustments();

break_time_adjustments();

const session_time_adjustments = () => {
  // Getting all elements to set the length of a session
  const increase_session_time_button = document.querySelector(
      ".session-length-div .value-adjustment .plus"
    ),
    decrease_session_time_button = document.querySelector(
      ".session-length-div .value-adjustment .minus"
    ),
    session_time_value = document.querySelector(
      ".session-length-div .value-adjustment .minutes"
    );

  // Performing Operations on the elements
  let session_time = 25;
  session_time_value.innerHTML = session_time;

  // Getter function to retrieve the current session time
  const get_session_time = () => session_time;

  // Setter function to update the session time and display it
  const set_session_time = (newTime) => {
    session_time = newTime;
    session_time_value.innerHTML = session_time;
  };

  // Increasing the length of Session
  function increase_session_time() {
    set_session_time(session_time + 5); // Increasing length of Session time by 5
  }

  increase_session_time_button.addEventListener("click", increase_session_time);

  // Decreasing the length of Session
  function decrease_session_time() {
    if (session_time <= 0) {
      session_time = 0;
    } else {
      set_session_time(session_time - 5); // Decreasing length of Session time by 5
    }
  }

  decrease_session_time_button.addEventListener("click", decrease_session_time);

  // Return getter and setter functions
  return {
    get_session_time,
    set_session_time
  };
};

const {
  get_session_time,
  set_session_time
} = session_time_adjustments();

// Initializing a variable to store session interval id
let session_interval_id;

const update_time = (session_duration) => {
  // Getting elements to update the Time
  const Time = document.querySelector(".time");
  const heading = document.querySelector(".session .heading");
  heading.innerHTML = "Session";

  let minutes = session_duration;
  let seconds = 0;

  // Updating Time

  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer when it reaches 0
      break_time(get_break_time()); // Start the break
      // break_time(1); // For testing
      return;
    }

    if (seconds === 0) {
      minutes--;
      seconds = 59;
    } else {
      seconds--;
    }

    Time.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? "0" : ""}${seconds}`;
  }, 1000);

  session_interval_id = timer;

  return timer;
};

// Initializing a varibale to store break time interval id
let break_interval_id;

const break_time = (break_duration_time) => {
  //Getting elements to start break time
  const Time = document.querySelector(".time");
  const heading = document.querySelector(".session .heading");
  heading.innerHTML = "Break";

  // Starting Break time
  let break_duration = break_duration_time;
  let minutes = break_duration;
  let seconds = 0;

  const break_timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
      clearInterval(break_timer); // Stop the timer when it reaches 0
      update_time(get_session_time());
      // update_time(1); // For Testing
      return;
    }

    if (seconds === 0) {
      minutes--;
      seconds = 59;
    } else {
      seconds--;
    }

    Time.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? "0" : ""}${seconds}`;
  }, 1000);

  break_interval_id = break_timer;

  return break_timer;
};

const start = () => {
  // Getting elements to start the clock
  const start_button = document.querySelector(".controls .start-button button");

  // Flag to check if previous session is already running
  let is_session_running = false;

  // Starting the clock
  function start_clock() {
    if (is_session_running) {
      clearInterval(session_interval_id); // Clearing previous session
      clearInterval(break_interval_id); // Clearing previous break
    }

    update_time(get_session_time());
    // update_time(1); // For Testing
    is_session_running = true;
  }

  start_button.addEventListener("click", start_clock);
};

start();

const stop = () => {
  // Getting Elements to stop the clock
  const reset_button = document.querySelector(".controls .reset-button button");
  const heading = document.querySelector(".session .heading");
  const Timer = document.querySelector(".session .time");

  // Adding funcionality to stop button
  function reset_the_timer() {
    clearInterval(session_interval_id);
    clearInterval(break_interval_id);
    heading.innerHTML = "Start";
    Timer.innerHTML = "00:00";
  }

  reset_button.addEventListener("click", reset_the_timer);
};

stop();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #0e9aa7;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.app-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.double-line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.app-title p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

.adjustment-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 80%;
}

.break-length-div,
.session-length-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 130px;
}

.break-length-div .heading,
.session-length-div .heading {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.value-adjustment {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 90%;
}

.minus,
.plus {
  background: transparent;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  color: #3db9c5;
  border: 1px #3db9c5 solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.minus:hover,
.plus:hover {
  color: #2dd6e6;
  border-color: #2dd6e6;
}

.value-adjustment .minutes {
  background-color: white;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.session {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #3db9c5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.session .heading {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

.session .time {
  font-size: 76px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}

.start-button button,
.reset-button button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #3db9c5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.start-button button:hover,
.reset-button button:hover {
  border-color: #2dd6e6;
}

.remarks {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: #80e4eb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Pomodoro Clock</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="app-title">
      <div class="double-line"></div>
      <p>Pomodoro Clock</p>
      <div class="double-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="adjustment-div">
      <div class="break-length-div">
        <p class="heading">Break Length</p>
        <div class="value-adjustment">
          <button class="minus">-</button>
          <div class="minutes"></div>
          <button class="plus">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="session-length-div">
        <p class="heading">Session Length</p>
        <div class="value-adjustment">
          <button class="minus">-</button>
          <div class="minutes"></div>
          <button class="plus">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="session">
      <div class="heading">
        Start
      </div>
      <div class="time">
        00:00
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="reset-button">
        <button>Reset</button>
      </div>
      <div class="start-button">
        <button>Start</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="remarks">
      Designed based on a pen by <u>Edd Yerburgh</u> and code by <u>Crying Wolfe</u>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Key Features:**

**Modularization:** I modularized my code by breaking it down into functions for adjusting break and session times, updating the time display, starting the session, and stopping/resetting the clock. This approach promotes code reuse and maintainability.

**Event Handling:** Event listeners are used to handle user interactions, such as increasing/decreasing break and session times, starting the clock, and resetting it, making the application interactive and user-friendly.

**Error Handling:** I implemented basic error handling to ensure that session and break times do not become negative and are capped at a minimum of 0.

**Functionality:** The Pomodoro clock alternates between session and break periods based on user-defined times, providing a functional and intuitive experience.

**Request for Feedback:**
I would appreciate feedback on the overall structure and readability of my code, as well as suggestions for optimization and improvement. Additionally, any advice on best practices or alternative approaches would be valuable for my learning journey.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: Do you have any specific question about the code? If you seek feedback with a working application, please move your question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I made a snippet of your code so it runs here and formatted it a bit.  Visually the results overlap on each other a bit at smaller screen sizes. Personally not a fan of the underscore name form especially when mixed with other styles.  IF you have to have a comment then the name probably needs adjusted    `// Increasing the length of Break
  function increase_break_time() {` vs  something like `function increaseBreakDuration() {` or say what 5 is `function increaseBreakDuration(minutes=5) {
    setBreakTime(breakTime + minutes);
  }` which allows it to vary `increaseBreakDuration(3);`